# Front and back synchronization failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm creating a web with a Django backend and React frontend.
When posting an object from the front and trying to fetch it, it doesn't work unless I restart the backend, when it should update instantly.
In the admin view it shows right away, but it cannot fetch it for some reason until I restart

Here is the settings file in case is relevant

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import xmlrunner

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, 'petRecognition', 'model')
DEMO_PICTURES_DIR = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, 'petRecognition', 'media')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-vbkt_liurmfu7$18-v#&n9+!zneamzit*)aeltd+6$*gkpqjgd'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

TEST_RUNNER = 'xmlrunner.extra.djangotestrunner.XMLTestRunner'
TEST_OUTPUT_DIR = './backend/test-outputs/'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 26214400

# Configuración correo SMTP gmail
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'petfinderpin@outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'PIS2000!'


# Actual directory user files go to
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
# URL used to access the media
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

And this is the view I'm retrieving that doesn't update on runtime

```
class PublicadosListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = list(Resenya.objects.filter(estado='publicado')) + list(Consulta.objects.filter(estado='publicado'))

    permission_classes = []
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        # Utiliza el serializador adecuado según el tipo de objeto
        if isinstance(self.queryset[0], Resenya):
            return ResenyaSerializer
        elif isinstance(self.queryset[0], Consulta):
            return ConsultaSerializer
```

I have tried adding the item from the admin view, postman and the frontend, but it only shows when the server restarts. Any clue why that might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the view, since it was set to a static list of objects.
Fixed it with the following code:

```
class PublicadosListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = []

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if isinstance(self.get_queryset()[0], Resenya):
            return ResenyaSerializer
        elif isinstance(self.get_queryset()[0], Consulta):
            return ConsultaSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = list(Resenya.objects.filter(estado='publicado')) + list(Consulta.objects.filter(estado='publicado'))
        return queryset
```